# VBA Array to copy paste data from one workbook to another

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Below is my code using array to have data from SW to DW.Code is not throwing any error but data is also not pasted in to DW. What I am trying to do is to find AG-last row of data in SW and then assign it to Arr and trying to copy the same in to DW. My source workbook is in my C drive.

```
Sub Arr()
    Dim SW AS Workbook
    Dim DW As Worksheet
    Dim Arr as Variant

    Set DW = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample")
    Set SW = Workbooks.Open ("C:\User\filename.xlsx")

    Lastrow = SW.Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUP).Row

    Arr = SW.Sheets("data").Range("A3:AG" & Lastrow)
    DW.Range("A2").Value = Arr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

`DW.Range("A2").resize(ubound(arr,1),ubound(arr,2)).Value = Arr`

You are trying to put the whole array into one cell.

Comment: @SharmilaV [this cpearson article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) about arrays and ranges is very useful for understanding how this answer works and why.

Comment: @Mods - so asking someone to accept answers is beyond the pale? I thought it was one of the central planks of the site.